# Certificate issue when using artifactory as docker registry

Tags: docker, artifactory

I have an artifactory instance configured as a docker registry and docker swarm configured to use this docker registry.

The artifactory instance has hostname art1.mydomain but there is also a cname artifactory.mydomain in DNS resolving to the same IP address.

The artifactory instance is configured to use a certificate with Subject artifactory.mydomain, but art1.mydomain is not a subject.
dockerd is configured to use https://artifactory.mydomain:port as the registry mirror.

When I try to do "docker image pull" from one of the docker swarm nodes, it appears that artifactory initially returns an HTTP 401 response asking for authentication, but the url it passes with the HTTP 401 response is for https://art1.mydomain:port not https://artifactory.mydomain:port.

The subsequent /v2/token request from docker then fails because art1.mydomain doesn't match the certificate.
Is there a way to configure artifactory to not use its hostname in the url returned with the HTTP 401 response?

Comment: Please post the `docker pull` command that you're using

Comment: Just a normal command like "docker image pull library/nginx:1.10.3-alpine".

Comment: Have you configured the "Custom Base URL" in the Admin --> Configuration --> General Configuration?